# How to achieve black&white-friendly syntax highlighting in PDFs produced with knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am writing a document with knitr (Rnw to be processed to PDF) that will be printed in black&white. I still would like the code chunks to have syntax highlighting.

Is it possible, and how, to modify default syntax highlighting colors to use some shades of gray etc.?

PS. I do not want to switch to LaTeX 'listings' package.

Comment: Have a look at `help("knit_theme")`. Maybe one of the themes fulfills your requirements?

Comment: @Roland, thanks. I should have followed knitr development more closely... ;-) Didn't know about themes. That should be the way to go.

Comment: If you find a good theme for black/white printing, please add an answer to your question. Might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Roland, knitr themes (`?knit_theme`) do the job. In particular, the `print` theme seems to suite black-and-white printing best. A gallery of all built-in knitr themes can be found here http://animation.r-forge.r-project.org/knitr/

In particular, to set `print` theme in my Rnw document put this in the initial R code chunk:

```
opts_knit$set( out.format="latex" )
knit_theme$set("print")
```